# variable for match attribute of xslt template tag

Tags: templates, xslt, variables, match

Is it possible to set a variable name for the match attribute value in xslt template tag.
Any help?

Comment: No in XSLT 1.0. But nothing prevents the usage of `document()` function...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure about what you want to achieve, but here is an example:

```
   <!-- a variable -->
   <xsl:variable name="x" select="//some/path"/>

   <!-- a template to match all elements with the name of the variable -->
   <xsl:template match="*[name(.)=$x]">
       Yes! <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Match patterns cannot contain variables in XSLT 1.0

Comment: This should be in a separate answer. I just spent 2 days finding this error, because neither Xalan-J, nor PHP's XSLTProcessor class detect this as a syntax error.